# pip --cache-dir vs version range

Tags: python, pip

Will `pip` only use `--cache-dir` cache to satisfy the range version of a requirement or will it update the cache if a newer version is available within that range?

Example:

- requirements.txt contains **requests>=2.0,<3.0**
- cache contains **requests==2.3.4**
- remote pypi now has **requests==2.4** available

Will `pip install --cache-dir=... requirements.txt` find the new version available and update the cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if **requests==2.3.4** is already installed in the current environment (the global `/site-packages/` or a virtual environment). If the version is installed and you don't use the option `-U/--upgrade`, `pip` will not download a new version and will not use the cached version.

If **requests** isn't installed `pip` will download any newer version allowed by constraints (**2.4** in your example), cache it and install.

The cache will be used next time you run `pip install requirements.txt` with the same constraints (providing that no new version of the package appears at PyPI in the meantime).